MongoDB with replica set: authentication failed for MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME & PASSWORD
I have a simple mongodb docker container. I use the official docker image, but override the entrypoint to fix some file permissions.
The env variables for MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME and MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD are set.
The entrypoint script looks like this:
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

mounted_keyfile="/keyfile"
mongo_keyfile="/mongo-keyfile"

# Copy the mounted keyfile, since we don't want to change the file on the host
cp $mounted_keyfile $mongo_keyfile

# Ensure the keyfile is owned by root and has the correct permissions
chown root:root $mongo_keyfile
chmod 400 $mongo_keyfile

exec mongod --auth --replSet rs0 --keyFile $mongo_keyfile --bind_ip_all


The docker compose looks like this:
version: "3"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:7.0.4
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "${DEVENV_MONGO_USER}"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DEVENV_MONGO_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - "${DEVENV_MONGO_PORT}:27017"
    entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
    healthcheck:
      test: test $(mongosh --quiet --eval "rs.status().ok") -eq 1
      interval: 10s
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/keyfile:/keyfile:ro
      - ./mongo/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
      - mongo_data:/data/db

volumes:
  mongo_data:

DEVENV_MONGO_USER is set to "root".
DEVENV_MONGO_PASSWORD is set to "rootpassword".
When I then try to use the mongosh to do anything via
docker exec mongo mongosh -u root -p rootpassword

I get a "Authentication failed" error.
mongod log of failed connection:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-18T07:32:16.562+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:39478","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"816fdbe1-80d5-4d58-83a2-1e32198a4d9f"}},"connectionId":5023,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-18T07:32:16.567+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn5023","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:39478","client":"conn5023","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.1.1"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.3.0|2.1.1"},"platform":"Node.js v20.9.0, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"6.6.26-1-MANJARO","type":"Linux"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-18T07:32:16.570+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:39484","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"06465047-9444-4159-a92e-10c522d14373"}},"connectionId":5024,"connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-18T07:32:16.571+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn5024","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:39484","client":"conn5024","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.1.1"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.3.0|2.1.1"},"platform":"Node.js v20.9.0, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"6.6.26-1-MANJARO","type":"Linux"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-18T07:32:16.572+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20251,   "ctx":"conn5024","msg":"Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user","attr":{"user":{"user":"root","db":"admin"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-18T07:32:16.572+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":6788604, "ctx":"conn5024","msg":"Auth metrics report","attr":{"metric":"acquireUser","micros":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-18T07:32:16.572+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":5286307, "ctx":"conn5024","msg":"Failed to authenticate","attr":{"client":"127.0.0.1:39484","isSpeculative":true,"isClusterMember":false,"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","user":"root","db":"admin","error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"root\" for db \"admin\"","result":11,"metrics":{"conversation_duration":{"micros":66,"summary":{"0":{"step":1,"step_total":2,"duration_micros":50}}}},"extraInfo":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-18T07:32:16.573+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":6788604, "ctx":"conn5024","msg":"Auth metrics report","attr":{"metric":"acquireUser","micros":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-18T07:32:16.573+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":5286307, "ctx":"conn5024","msg":"Failed to authenticate","attr":{"client":"127.0.0.1:39484","isSpeculative":false,"isClusterMember":false,"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","user":"root","db":"admin","error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"root\" for db \"admin\"","result":11,"metrics":{"conversation_duration":{"micros":297,"summary":{"0":{"step":1,"step_total":2,"duration_micros":284}}}},"extraInfo":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-18T07:32:16.575+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn5023","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:39478","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"816fdbe1-80d5-4d58-83a2-1e32198a4d9f"}},"connectionId":5023,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-04-18T07:32:16.579+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn5024","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:39484","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"06465047-9444-4159-a92e-10c522d14373"}},"connectionId":5024,"connectionCount":0}}


Specifying the auth database does not fix this. I also tried using another user name, in case it conflicts with the linux root user, but that also did not have any effect.
I assume it has something to do with the replica set or keyfile, but I could not find anything online which worked.

Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

@WernfriedDomscheit Sadly that is not applicable. I am using the initdb root user, which is always created in admin. At this point my DB does not even have any "wrong" databases to connect to. I even delete the mongo_data volume after each run, to ensure I don't carry over any weird config leftovers.

I am not familiar with docker. Does it run rs.initiate()?

Check the mongod log, it should show you exactly which account and database were used when it fails

@WernfriedDomscheit Yes, I do run the rs.initiate() after mongo starts (in a separate call).

@Joe The mongod log tells me the user does not exist (adding the relevant section to the question). But how is that possible if I use the MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME to log in? This user should always exist, or am I mistaken?

Ok, note after running rs.initiate() you have to wait some time till initialization is finished. Put while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) sleep(1000) after it. An other note, first you have to initialize the replica set, then create the admin user.

@WernfriedDomscheit There usually is a significant time between starting mongod and running the mongosh command. I tried adding the db.hello().isWritablePrimary, but the authentication error is unchanged.

Through trial and error I managed to find the issue. It was either that the mongo docker container is not supposed to run as root or that the file permissions were somehow wrong.
I ended up creating a "init" container to set the permissions correctly and then run the mongo as the non-root user 1000.
My docker compose now looks like this:
version: "3"
services:
  mongo-init:
    image: busybox
    command: /bin/sh -c 'cp /keyfile /mongo/my-keyfile && chmod 400 /mongo/my-keyfile && chown -R 1000:1000 /mongo'
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/keyfile:/keyfile:ro
      - mongo_data:/mongo:rw

  mongo:
    image: mongo:7.0.4
    restart: on-failure
    user: "1000:1000"
    depends_on:
      mongo-init:
        condition: "service_completed_successfully"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "${DEVENV_MONGO_USER}"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DEVENV_MONGO_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - "${DEVENV_MONGO_PORT}:27017"
    command: --auth --replSet rs0 --keyFile /data/db/my-keyfile
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
volumes:
  mongo_data:


I could also completely ditch the custom entrypoint.sh.
If anyone wants to add an answer to explain why this now works, I will gladly accept it. For now I just wanted to add my working setup in case someone runs into the same issue.
